# Mysql - best way to replace text

Tags: mysql

I need to replace the following text in one of columns:

> #post{some numbers}

to

> #post-{some numbers}

What is the best and most efficient way to do so?
I have found regex replace for mysql: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660574/5417374

But wonder if there is more marter way.

Comment: are there also `#post{not numbers}` lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one-off, I would just create a script in your language of choice reading all the rows, replacing it with said languages' rexep function of your choice and writing it back.

If this is a regular occurance, I would do this again in code, but before entering it in the database.

I see no specific need to do this in `sql`.

Comment: Ok, the only solution i see (maybe a little but slow due to amount of records - over 2 mln).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query, I assume "some numbers" as numbers.

```
select concat(substr("#post{123456}", 1, INSTR("#post{123456}",'{')-1),"-",substr("#post{123456}", INSTR("#post{123456}",'{'),length("#post{123456}")-(INSTR("#post{123456}",'{')-1) ))
```